# Spring security OAuth parsing the response into an object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm new to spring.

I have been following http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ using google oauth in place of facebook.

I am able to return the principle as described in the tutorial, which sends to the browser the json returned by the api call and can use this client side.

```
@RestController
public class UserControllers {
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

But how would I use this data on the server side? Suppose I wanted just to return the email address on the /user route? Or maybe I want to further populate the Principal with information from a database?

Below is the code I use to set up the oauth authentication. 
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableOAuth2Client
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http    .csrf().disable() 
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll() //logout logic handled by spring
                .and()
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**", "/user")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    protected Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(constructFilter("/login/google", google(), googleResource()));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter constructFilter(String endpoint, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails clientDetails, ResourceServerProperties resourceDetails) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new CustomOauth2AuthFilter(endpoint); 
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(clientDetails, oauth2ClientContext); 
        filter.setRestTemplate(template);
        filter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(resourceDetails.getUserInfoUri(), clientDetails.getClientId()));
        return filter;
    }


    /*
    /Returns a new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails object configured with the properties from the application.yml file
     */
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("google.client")
    OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails google() {
        return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
    }

    /*
    /Returns a new ResourceServerProperties object configured with the properties from the application.yml file
     */
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("google.resource")
    ResourceServerProperties googleResource() {
        return new ResourceServerProperties();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Dan